# Dividing point layer according to boundary layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, layers, splitting, multi-polygon

I have two layers:

- All the post offices in the city (point layer)
- Division of the city into boundaries according to their neighbourhood council (MultiPolygon layer)

How do I split the first layer into multiple layers according to the different neighbourhoods?

In order words, there are 9 different neighbourhoods in the city and I would like to get 9 layers that include the post offices in each neighbourhood.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Can you add a little more information about the geometry type of the two layers ?

Comment: Hi, thank you! The first layer is a point layer whereas the second layer is a multipolygon. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two steps :

1. First, [an intersection](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection) between the point layer (1st) and the polygon layer (2nd) and retrieve an identifier field data from the second one.
2. Then, [split the resulting intersection point layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer) and choose identifier field from the polygon layer to split the point layer.

The splitted layers are saved in an output directory, you just have to load them after the split processing.

Comment: Thank you very much!